# Term for universally-used quote with additional, non-compositional meaning

Tags: terminology, semantics, sociolinguistics, lexicon, idiomaticity

There exist certain fixed expressions which people use to convey quite specific meanings and (at least to me) always invoke a famous saying which is assumed to be common knowledge, such as

- [*I am not a crook*](https://youtu.be/sh163n1lJ4M?t=30s) (AFAIK primarily American English), denoting that the speaker has done something dubious
- [*I have a cunning plan*](https://youtu.be/AsXKS8Nyu8Q?t=9s) (AFAIK primarily British English), denoting the proposition of an absurd/risky/generally bad idea

However, it seems to me that these phrases are not typical [idioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom) because their meaning is at least partly compositional, unlike e.g. *kick the bucket*: Nevertheless, they invoke a more nuanced meaning than the composition of the words themselves implies, and there even seems to be some [contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_distribution) between these expressions and a pure generative usage of the above phrases:

- *I'm not a crook!* → The speaker is not a crook (unmarked meaning)
- (said in a stilted voice) *I am not a crook.* → The speaker has done something dubious

**Is there any terminology commonly used for describing this specific phenomenon?**

Comment: Quotation? Allusion? Intertextuality?

Comment: They'd be considered cliches - overused set phrases. Cliches aren't just limited to ironic meanings. The examples you've given do seem to have pretty compositional meanings though they are now used more ironically.